# How to expose a flask application running inside an Openshift pod

Tags: python, kubernetes, flask, openshift

I created a flask app which I need to run inside an OCP pod. The pod has a python container, and the app is a basic flask app.
When I run the app with `python app.py` the app is exposed at `0.0.0.0:5000`.

Currently, there is no need to create a Docker image for it, and I cannot create a deployment for the app because its has to run as a little 'sidecar' container and the app's initiation will run with another automation tool.

The app is running and when I run `curl 0.0.0.0:5000` from within the pod it prints the app's content.

I tried to create a service with `oc expose pod <python-pod-name> --port=5000 --name=flask` and then running  `oc expose svc flask` to create a route, I tried to access the url with `<url>:5000` and also tried `http://<url>`, but no success.

Here are the route specs:

```
spec:
  host: <host>
  to:
    kind: Service
    name: flask
    weight: 100
  port:
    targetPort: 5000
  wildcardPolicy: None
```

Service's yaml:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: flask
specs:
  clusterIP: <cluster's IP address>
  ipFamilies:
    - IPv4
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 5000
      targetPort: 5000
  internalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  type: ClusterIP
```

I would like to know if I'm missing something, and If there is another way of doing that.

Answer (score 1):

When you expose a service via a [Route](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.14/networking/routes/route-configuration.html), it is handled by the OpenShift ingress service, which listens on ports 80 and 443. Your application will be available on one or both of those ports (so either `http://...` or `https://...`) depending on how you've configured the route.

The ingress router will accept requests on ports 80 or 443, then proxy those to your service on `spec.port.targetPort`.